# What is a good way to store, walking/running data for a steps calculator?

Tags: ios, mobile

For a steps calculator app, I am trying to store walking/running data and I am wondering what would be a good way to do that so that I can pull it up later when I need it. For eg. to show users their history of how much distance they walked.
I could think of two approaches:

- Send all the location data\coordinates from client to the server and let server calculate the distance walked.
- Calculate the distance in the client itself and keep updating the server in the background at regular intervals. The server in this case, would get data in distance units and not as co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would choose whichever approach would allow for the most responsiveness for the user.  In my mind, your second approach would be more correct.  If you're doing the calculations natively, I imagine you could deliver information to your user faster.  Then, you could always sync the data to your server in the background later. Further, if there was a problem with a network connection, you could run into a data delivery problem that would result in losing users.  Best of luck whichever you choose, and let us know what you decide and why.